# Retrieve phone number with the help of id in facebook

Tags: android, facebook, json

[image]I am able to retrieve most of the information with the help of id in facebook.Is it possible to retrieve phone number of friends,because Json Array generated after parsing id is not giving the phone number.If it is, then how?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/446/

Comment: well the comments there say that this is no longer available; try to see if you get the data using user_address, if not you're out of luck

Comment: Ok....Again a better luck try....

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to retrieve the friends phone number once they come to your app and grant you the permissions. To get that friend to come to the app, you need to make your app so cool that each user will want to have all their friends using the app too.  It's a hard challenge, but it can be done, take a look at FarmVille, etc for some inspiration .